# PIne Script - EMA into a 'Checkbox' Boolean input?

Tags: pine-script

sorry for being such a newb and asking this silly question but does anyone know how to turn an EMA into a toggle switch (checkbox) input in TradingView?

Example - having an EMA 200 line drawn unto the chart and having the option to open the settings and toggling it On/OFF with a checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can click the style tab in the settings menu and turn it off there.

Alternatively you could do the following:

```
showMA = input(title='Show EMA', type=input.bool, defval=true)

myEMA = ema(close, 200)

plot(showMA ? myEMA : na)
```

Comment: Is there a way to also make it stop doing its function when you uncheck it from the Inputs panel? I have the Ema plotted to a 'plotshape' that gives a signal on the chart when price is above the Ema or below it

Comment: Pinescript will give you a warning if you were to put it in an if statement, generally I don't think it's good practice to do so. You make your condition: `over = close > myEMA` and then do `plotshape(showMA ? over : na, ...)`